# Publish Expo React Native to Apple Store (Application Loader not Showing)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, application-loader

I could build my react native app using `expo build:ios` and I have the .ipa file. I went to App Store Connect to upload my app. However, it is not showing an option to download the `Application Loader`. How can I get the Application Loader or upload without it?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Application Loader is only available on MacOS**. If you are using Windows or Linux, I recommend you installing a **virtual machine** (for example using *VirtualBox*). You can follow this link: https://techsprobe.com/macos-mojave/

After installing the virtual machine, you can easily install Application Loader there.

Comment: Please post a step wise answer and then reference links.

Comment: I'm using MacOS. Application Loader is not available anymore. I had to use Transporter app